# Counting the number of edges traversed in a Breadth First Search?

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

This is my bfs algorithim. I want to store the number of edges i traversed in the field edges, but I can't figure out where to place the variable to add one for each edge. I keep getting answers that are too long, so i think this is harder than simply incrementing edge.

It should be noted that this is supposed to calculate the edges along the true path only, not the extra edges.

```
public int distance(Vertex x, Vertex y){
        Queue<Vertex> search = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
        search.add(x);
        x.visited = true;
        while(!search.isEmpty()){
            Vertex t = search.poll();
            if(t == y){
                return edges;
            }
            for(Vertex n: t.neighbours){
                if(!n.visited){
                    n.visited = true;
                    search.add(n);
                }

            }
            System.out.println(search + " " + t);
        }
        return edges;   
    }
```

Any and all help is appreciated. if you require more classes/methods let me know

EDIT

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Vertex {

    public static char currentID = 'a';
    protected ArrayList<Vertex> neighbours;
    protected char id;
    protected boolean visited = false;
    protected Vertex cameFrom = null;
    public Vertex(){
        neighbours = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        id = currentID;
        currentID++;
        Graph.all.add(this);
    }
    public void addNeighbour(Vertex x){
        int a;
        while(x == this){
             a = (int) (Math.random()*(Graph.all.size()));
             x = Graph.all.get(a);
        }           
            if(!(neighbours.contains(x))){
                neighbours.add(x);
                x.addNeighbour(this);
                //System.out.println(this + " Linking to " + x);
            }
    }
    public void printNeighbours(){
        System.out.println("The neighbours of: " + id + " are: " + neighbours);
    }
    public String toString(){
        return id + "";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Vertex` class, create a `Vertex cameFrom` field which you set to point to the `Vertex` you came from when that node was visited. You could even replace your `boolean visited` field with this (if it is `null` the `Vertex` hasn't been visited yet).

Then, when you find the `Vertex y` just follow the pointers back to `Vertex x` counting how many steps it takes as you go.

If you don't want to change your `Vertex` class, then just keep a `Map<Vertex,Vertex>` during your search which stores the mappings from the vertex you're visiting to the vertex you came from. When you get to the end you can follow the path to the beginning in the same way.

---

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
    public int distance(Vertex x, Vertex y){
        Queue<Vertex> search = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
        search.add(x);
        while(!search.isEmpty()){
            Vertex t = search.poll();
            if(t == y){
                return pathLength( t );
            }
            for(Vertex n: t.neighbours){
                if(n.cameFrom == null || n != x){
                    n.cameFrom = t;
                    search.add(n);
                }

            }
            System.out.println(search + " " + t);
        }
        return -1;  
    }

    public int pathLength( Vertex v )
    {
       int path = 0;

       while ( v.cameFrom != null )
       {
         v = v.cameFrom;
         path++;
       }

       return path;
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by pointer? I've never done something like this before, maybe a code snippet? Thanks!

Comment: oh! This may work! I will try and if it does you get upvote + accept :D

Comment: I hope it does work for you. I added some sample code to make my point more clear, although I haven't tested it carefully since I don't  have your other classes.

Comment: will this really work?  What if a given vertex has multiple incoming connections?

Comment: Oh dear, he is right, The vertexes can have more than one connection. I'm not sure if this will work. I'm implementing it now, it should work since BFS stops at the shortest path, but we will see..

Comment: For some reason, when i implement this, it just doesnt return anything at all, not even 0.

Comment: I fixed that, but unfortunatley the multiple incoming paths breaks this :(

Comment: How do you have multiple incoming paths? Once the node has been visited it looks like your logic doesn't allow it to be visited again.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's managing to set it improperly, but each Vertex can have any number of neighbours, with no exclusions. Maybe my implementation was wrong. I'm gonna try again.

Comment: The not returning anything problem was caused by `x.cameFrom` being null, as implemented you need an extra check to make sure `n != x` so you don't keep going back to the first node. After fixing that it seems to be working for me...

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the number of edges is simply the size of the `search`. queue.

EDIT:

One possible solution is to do it layer by layer.  Lets say you asked for the distance between Vertex A, F

and the Graph looks like:

```
A
|\
B C
|
D
|\
E F
```

First calculate the distance between A and B,C (which is easy because B and C are immediate neighbors of A.  Then calculate the distance between A and D (which is easy because D is an immediate neighbor of B, then A and E, F.  Store the distance in the A vertex node.  Now after you've run the BFS and determined the search result, you can simply ask for the distance.  Look at [this](http://seed.ucsd.edu/mediawiki/images/b/b2/Lec5.pdf) visual diagram.

Comment: What do you mean? I need the edges of the path between two vertexs, when i get the size of search, i don't get that.

Comment: OK I think you need to update your question with that caveat.

Comment: It should be noted that this is supposed to calculate the edges along the true path only, not the extra edges. 

It's right there....

Comment: OK - I read that wrong the first time.  Let me see if I can amend my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it would be appreciated!

Comment: I may be implementing this wrong, but this gives me the wrong answer if the graph includes cycles.

Comment: How are you implementing this?  It seems like a detail that you can fix by checking if the node you're examining *is* the current node

Comment: Could you give me a code snippet? I'm having a lot of trouble implementing this.

Comment: Paste your Vertex class and I'll give it a shot

Comment: hey, don't bother, thanks for the help though, i got the other method working! You stioll get upvote :)