# I am unable to display the path taken inside my maze from start to finish 

Tags: java

I am reading the maze outline in from an input file and storing the values in a 2D array. I am able to find the exit in my findPath() method, but i am unsure how to trace the actual  path from start to finish.

I want to change the char value in the "Room" to a '.' if it is on the actual path. Please advise how i can accomplish this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Maze {
    String inFile,   // Name of file to be used as input
           outFile,  // Name of file to output completed maze to
           line;     // Current line being read by scanner
    Room [][] rooms; // Holds the values that create maze
    Room [] theStack;
    Room goal;
    Room current = new Room();
    int rows, columns;
    int tos = 0;
    char [][] mazeC;

    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
        Maze m = new Maze();
    }

    public Maze() throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Prompts user for the name of the file they wish to use as the input file.
        inFile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the name of the file you wish to read, including " + "the file path:");
        if(inFile.equals("")) inFile = "C:/java/javaFiles/maze1.txt";

        // Prompts user to enter the name they wish to save the file under.
        outFile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the filename you wish to save the data to:");
        if(outFile.equals("")) outFile = "C:/java/javaFiles/mazeoutput1.txt";

        // Creates a scanner object to read in the input file.
        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(inFile));
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outFile);        
        rows = readFile.nextInt();
        columns = readFile.nextInt();
        readFile.nextLine();
        theStack = new Room[1000];
        rooms = new Room [rows][columns];
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            line = readFile.nextLine();
            for(int j = 0; j< line.length(); j++) {
                Room r = new Room();
                r.setValue(line.charAt(j));
                if(r.getValue() == '$')
                    r.setGoal(true);
                r.setBlocked(false);
                if (r.getValue() == '*') {
                    r.setBlocked(true);
                    r.setGoal(false);
                } else {
                    r.setGoal(false);
                    r.setBlocked(false);
                }
                r.setCord(i, j);
                rooms[i][j] = r;
                //mazeContent[i][j]  = line.charAt(j);    
            }
        }

        createRooms();

        findPath();
        for(int i = 0; i < rows ; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < columns ; j++) {
                System.out.print(rooms[i][j].getValue());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void createRooms() {
        for(int i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j < columns -1; j++) {
                rooms[i][j].setCord(i,j);
                rooms[i][j].setValue(rooms[i][j].getValue());
                rooms[i][j].setUp(rooms, i, j);
                rooms[i][j].setDown(rooms, i, j);
                rooms[i][j].setRight(rooms, i, j);
                rooms[i][j].setLeft(rooms, i, j);
                if(rooms[i][j].getValue() == '*')
                    rooms[i][j].setBlocked(true);
                else
                    rooms[i][j].setBlocked(false);

                //System.out.println(rooms[i][j].getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    public void findPath() {
        for(int i = 0; i < rows ; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < columns ; j++) {
                System.out.print(rooms[i][j].getValue());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        Room start = rooms[1][1];
        push(start);
        while(!isEmpty()) { 
            current = pop();
            System.out.println("The value stored in current is" + current.getValue()+ "");
            if (current == null) 
                System.out.println("current is null");
            else if(current.getValue() == '$') {
                System.out.println("Success"); 
                current.setValue('f');
                /*for (int i = 0; i < tos; i++) {
                }*/
            }
            //System.out.println("The value is " + current.getValue());
            else if(current.getBlocked() == false && current.getVisited() == false) {
                System.out.println("pushing currents neighbors left, right....etc" + 
                    "current is at" +  current.getCord());
                current.setVisited(true);
                //
                if(current.getRight() != null){
                    push(current.getRight()); System.out.println("Inside push 1" +current.getRight().getCord());}
                else System.out.println("Inside push right is null");
                if(current.getLeft() != null){
                    push(current.getLeft()); System.out.println("Inside push 2 " + current.getLeft().getCord());}
                else System.out.println("Inside push left is null");
                if(current.getUp() != null)  {
                    push(current.getUp()); System.out.println("Inside push 3" + current.getUp().getCord());}
                else System.out.println("Inside push up is null");
                if(current.getDown() != null) {
                    push(current.getDown()); System.out.println("inside push 4" + current.getDown().getCord());}
                else System.out.println("Inside push down is null");
            }
        }
    }

    public Room pop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("I have Popped");
        return theStack[--tos];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return tos == 0;
    }

    public void push(Room item) {
        System.out.println("I have pushed");
        if (isFull()) {
            System.out.println("The stack is full!");
        }
        else if(item == null){
            System.out.println("you are pushing a null object");
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("stuff added");
        theStack[tos++] = item;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return tos == theStack.length-1;
    }
 }
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060144/counting-the-number-of-edges-traversed-in-a-breadth-first-search) is a question I asked a little while ago. While not the same thing, the general idea is the same. Consider using that sort of algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really gone through your code line by line but here's a solution: (*I wrote a similar program for finding Djikstra's shortest path in a graph*)

Make an attribute called *PREVIOUS* in your room object.
Every time you go to a 'next room', make sure you change your next room's *PREVIOUS* attribute to the room you came from.

**When you reach your destination:** Start with your destination's *PREVIOUS* and traverse back through the rooms until you hit a room with no *PREVIOUS*, which will be your source (start) room. **i.e.** go to the *PREVIOUS* room, add it to the stack, go to its *PREVIOUS* and repeat the process until you hit your starting room.

**This should work because:** If you go through a path of rooms and you hit a dead-end you will back track and start going through a new path. Eventually you will recursively over-write the *PREVIOUS* attribute for each room in your new path (every time). When you hit your destination, you will have the most updated (correct) *PREVIOUS* attribute in every room in your current (correct) path. So traverse back and add the *PREVIOUS* of each room to a stack or a queue or (whatever you want) as you go. This should give you your path.